# Getting different values using energy principle and momentum principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I tried solving this simple Newton's 2nd law problem using the energy principle instead as an excercise. The results were different... What did I do wrong? Below are my results:

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Phys.SE! You should try to write your question using MathJax, posting photos of equations is not encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivation using conservation of energy is wrong, because the total potential energy of the system when the mass is at its old equilibrium (unstretched spring) is *different* than the potential energy when the mass is at its new equilibrium (where the forces cancel).  Thus, one *cannot say* that $\Delta U = 0$.

In fact, if the mass starts at the equilibrium position of the *unstretched* spring, the mass will fall under the influence of gravity. This is because at the beginning, the force exerted by the spring is zero, whereas the gravitational force is non-zero. As the mass falls, the spring stretches, and hence the spring force increases.  At first, while the $F_{\mathrm{spring}}$ is smaller $F_{\mathrm{grav}}$, the mass accelerates. Once the mass moves through the new equilibrium position, $F_{\mathrm{spring}} > F_{\mathrm{grav}}$, and so the mass comes to a stop, at which point it will start to move upward.  In other words, the object undergoes oscillatory motion about the new equilibrium position.  It's true that energy is conserved, but this includes the kinetic energy, i.e.,
$$
0=\Delta E = \Delta K + \Delta U_{\mathrm{spring}}+ \Delta U_{\mathrm{grav}}\,.
$$

In order to get the object to start at the unstretched-spring equilibrium position and move to the actual equilibrium position, while having initial and final speeds be zero, there must be some *other* force doing work on the system, hence changing its energy.